# Is there a way to connect to Google Colab instance with Ubuntu 20.04 pre-installed?

Tags: google-colaboratory, ubuntu-20.04

I can upgrade a Colab instance to Ubuntu 20.04 using the commands below. However, it takes about 30 minutes every time so would be a huge timesaver if there were a way to not have to do this. I require Glibc 2.29 or greater, and as far as I can tell, this requires Ubuntu 20.04.

```
!sudo apt-mark unhold libcublas-dev && sudo apt-mark unhold libcublas10 && sudo apt-mark unhold libcudnn7 && sudo apt-mark unhold libcudnn7-dev && sudo apt-mark unhold libnccl-dev && sudo apt-mark unhold libnccl2

!sudo apt-get update

!sudo apt-get upgrade -y

!sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

!sudo apt install update-manager-core

!sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Where is your instance hosted?

Comment: @hedgie like geographically? I'm not sure. It's a Google Colab hosted runtime.

Comment: No, I meant at which company. The answer is obviously to ask this company to provide you with a current Ubuntu image. Colab can also be hosted by Amazon AWS EC2 where you can choose you own image. Instructions here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/d2l-ai/d2l-en-colab/blob/master/chapter_appendix-tools-for-deep-learning/aws.ipynb

Comment: ahh got it. i'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this method](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-install-glibc-2-29-or-higher-in-ubuntu-18-04) to use Glibc 2.29 in Ubuntu 18.04