# GLIBC_2.28 and GLIBC_2.29 not found on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, blender, glibc, libc, libm

How to install them?
When I start rendering a scene, I get this:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by ./Blender_K-cycles_linux/blender)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./Blender_K-cycles_linux/blender)

Is it even possible to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it even possible to install it?

No. Instead you should obtain a version of `blender` compiled for your target environment (current Google Colab appears to use Ubuntu 18.04).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65606052/50617).

Comment: I compiled the file, and it works!